# Missing Bookmarks Toolbar in Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, toolbar

My `Firefox 3.6.13` bookmarks toolbar is missing.

[image: Missing Bookmarks Toolbar in Firefox 3.6.13]

How can I restore it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by creating a new profile in Firefox. [Reference](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager)

Answer (score 1):

Choose `Customize...` from that right-click menu and in the popup, drag the "Bookmarks Toolbars Items" to the Bookmarks Toolbar.

Comment: I had some bookmarks in my `Bookmarks Toolbar` before, all of them are missing. Now, I can access to bookmarks items from `Bookmarks Menu`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have (by accident) moved your bookmarks to the menu, you should open the Bookmark Organizer from the Bookmarks menu and move your bookmarks back into the toolbar folder. If that doesn't work, try going to one of the sites and add the page to the toolbar again by dragging the favicon into the toolbar. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It appears bookmarks are missing - not the toolbar.  You might have deleted your bookmarks by accident! Do you remember the bookmarks in the toolbar?

Select `Organize bookmarks` in the Bookmarks menu and check if there are any bookmarks available in there.